VPN Strongswan traffic forwarding from local machine
I have four VPS machines linked together with permanent IPs on eth1. This is private traffic and cannot be accessed publically. One VM is my public proxy for all public access on eth0. My objective is to use one of the other servers as a VPN server on eth0 to allow me to access the servers through the subnet via eth1. I have the Strongswan VPN connecting from my local machine to the VPN server VM. I also want to send the 10.0.0.x remote traffic whilst still able to access internet on local development VM which I believe is called split traffic.
I don't know how far away or near I am from resolving this. I am a bit overwhelmed with dealing with such a topic for the first time.
I know I need to forward the traffic
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Somehow I need to make the IPs registered and an IP assigned for my local machine that fits with the rest of the IPs of the other servers on the subnet.
Local machine
sudo ipsec status

Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
    ikev2-rw[1]: ESTABLISHED 42 minutes ago, 192.168.xxx.xxx[leo]...139.162.xxx.xxx[139.162.xxx.xxx]
    ikev2-rw{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: cbe706cc_i cbd12172_o
    ikev2-rw{1}:   10.0.0.1/32 === 10.0.0.0/24

Local config Strongswan
conn ikev2-rw
    right=139.162.xxx.xxx
    rightid=139.162.xxx.xxx
    rightsubnet=10.0.0.0/24
    rightauth=pubkey
    leftsourceip=%config
    leftid=leo
    leftauth=eap-mschapv2
    eap_identity=%identity
    auto=start

remote VPN server Strnogswan
config setup
        charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0, net 1"
        strictcrlpolicy=no
        uniqueids=yes
        cachecrls=no
        install_virtual_ip_on = eth1

conn ipsec-ikev2-vpn
      auto=add
      compress=no
      type=tunnel
      keyexchange=ikev2
      fragmentation=yes
      forceencaps=yes
      dpdaction=clear
      dpddelay=300s
      rekey=no
      left=%any
      leftid=139.162.xxx.xxx
      leftcert=server.cert.pem
      leftsendcert=always
      leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
      right=%any
      rightid=%any
      rightauth=eap-mschapv2
      rightsourceip=10.0.0.0/24
      rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.8.4
      rightsendcert=never
      eap_identity=%identity
      ike=chacha20poly1305-sha512-curve25519-prfsha512,aes256gcm16-sha384-prfsha384-ecp384,aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
      esp=chacha20poly1305-sha512,aes256gcm16-ecp384,aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1,3des-sha1!


Apprciate any help to guide me to resolving this.
Thanks

What exactly is the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet in your scenario? A dedicated subnet for your VPN clients? Or is this the internal subnet the VPN server is connected to?

The servers are connect together on eth1 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.5. My ambition is to join that subnet through the VPN tunnel

i read your question again - it is the internal subnet the VPN server is connected to. The VPN server is also hosting some static websites and other 'services' for the project.

So some of these IPs are already in use? Then assigning them again to the VPN clients is no good (10.0.0.1 was assigned above). Either configure an offset (e.g. 10.0.0.10/24), or an unused range (e.g. 10.0.0.10-10.0.0.20) or use a different subnet for your clients. And if you don't do the latter, but use IPs from the same subnet for your clients, then you need the farp plugin so the VPN gateway will send ARP responses to the other servers for the IP addresses of your clients.

Thanks for the guidance.

So I need to install the farp plugin on the VPN server. Do I set an offset on the server config of the local config? (that would be the rightsourceip setting?)

In the server config. But that and the farp plugin are only necessary if you assign IPs from the server's LAN. You can also use a separate subnet for the VPN clients and avoid both (but it could be tricky if the VPN server is not the default gateway for hosts behind it that need to communicate with the VPN clients, see this for details).

I have checked for the farp plugin with ipsec statusall which showed farp in the active list. I added your suggested offset 10.0.0.10/24 and restarted. I can now ping the different servers from 10.0.0.1 - 4 and all respond. I cannot ssh into servers 10.0.0.1 - 3 but I can into 10.0.0.4 - this is the VPN server VM. What is blocking the ssh to the other servers 10.0.0.1 -3? Thanks

Difficult to say. Could be a firewall issue (filter or NAT, on gateway or individual servers).

I can ssh to these servers with the public IP's, where would I check the NAT or Gateway - the VPN server? Thanks
